# Put a bar at the bottom of a page

Tags: css

I need to put a fixed bar for showing a news title at the bottom of a page regardless of the page's height and device display height.

How can I do that using CSS?

Answer (score 31):

Set this bar's position property to fixed, and its bottom and left coordinates to 0. Set a high z-index so that it appears over top of whatever other content is at the bottom of the page at a given time. It will then stay stuck to the bottom of the browser window.

```
#someidentifier {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```